# What do 'bet money on money' and 'I’m for money against the field' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What do 'bet money on money' and 'I’m for money against the field' mean?

> “Now, don’t say that,” said old Anthony, shocked. “I bet my money on
>   money every time. I’ve been through the encyclopedia down to Y looking
>   for something you can’t buy with it; and I expect to have to take up
>   the appendix next week. I’m for money against the field. Tell me
>   something money won’t buy.”

[Mammon and the Archer
by O. Henry](https://americanenglish.state.gov/files/ae/resource_files/mammon-and-the-archer.pdf) (last paragraph of page 73)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I bet my money on money" means that the speaker believes money wins all contests. One could bet his money on a horse winning a race; to bet money on money itself is a humorous expression.

"The field" is probably a reference to horse racing, "all the runners in a race":
[Horse racing terms "field"](https://www.offtrackbetting.com/horse-racing-terms.html)

So, in context, it means means that money beats everything it is in competition with.